# How to update or create multiple array in the database

Tags: php, sql, laravel

how to updateOrCreate this array in database??

Image model contain id,title,src,

```
$data =[
          ["title"  => "toyota",  
           "src"    => "toyota5487"],
          ["title"  => "benz",
           "src"    => "benz5487"  ],
          ["title"  => "benz",
           "src"    => "benz5487"]
        ];
Image::updateOrCreate($data);
```

> error:Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
> found: 1054 Unknown column 'toyota' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
> from `images` where (`toyota` = toyota5487 and `benz` = benz5487)
> limit 1)

Comment: The SQL error message indicates missing quotation.

Comment: `updateOrCreate` takes 2 arguments and they are both just associative arrays ... and it only works on a single record

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#other-creation-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = [
    ['title'=>'toyota', 'src'=> 'toyota5487'],
    ['user_id'=>'benz', 'game_id'=> 'benz5487'],
    //...
];
```

**Eloquent approach**

```
Model::insert($data);
```

**Query Builder approach**

```
DB::table('table')->insert($data);
```

> Using the above method you can insert multiple entries in one query.

`updateorcreate` accepts 2 arguments one acts as where condition and other insert

**For example:**

```
// If there's a flight from Oakland to San Diego, set the price to $99.
// If no matching model exists, create one.
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

query builder [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate) take two arguments as associative array:

> Create or update a record matching the attributes, and fill it with
> values.

you can use it like:

```
$data =[
          ["title"  => "toyota",  
           "src"    => "toyota5487"],
          ["title"  => "benz",
           "src"    => "benz5487"  ],
          ["title"  => "benz",
           "src"    => "benz5487"]
        ];
  foreach ($data as $item)
        {
            Image::updateOrCreate($item);
        }
```

note that you can ignore the second argument if it's the same first one.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop each data, and then insert one by one using `$image = Image::updateOrCreate($data)`